# hide title is wordpress post doesn't have a title

Tags: wordpress

I believe things are getting warmer, the no title display correctly with blank, but the title now isn't a link nor a h2, it's just flat text. Any suggestions?

```
       <?php if (the_title()) { ?>

         <h2>
         <a href="'<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
         <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

       <?php } else { ?><?php }; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (get_the_title() != "") { ?>
    <h2><a href="'<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php } ?>
```

Should work.

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer as the solution by clicking the tick alongside for anyone else looking for the solution.